# Can non-approved email be used for test sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process

I'm planning to enable approval workflow in SFMC instance. Part of the approval process will include sending the email to a Seedlist for approval. I know it's not possible to send a non-approved email regularly, but is it possible to perform a test send with one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official documentation, it is possible:

> Before receiving approval, the user can conduct test sends to sample
>   audiences.

**Reference**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ds_approvals.htm&type=5